# Proving $\frac{n!}{x(x+1)\cdots(x+n)}=\frac{\binom n0}x-\frac{\binom n1}{x+1}+\cdots+(-1)^n\frac{\binom nn}{x+n}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to prove this problem?
$$\frac{n!}{x(x+1)\cdots(x+n)}=\frac{\binom n0}x-\frac{\binom n1}{x+1}+\cdots+(-1)^n\frac{\binom nn}{x+n}$$
I tried to solve the problem with induction but I don't know how.

Comment: Problems are meant to be solved, not proved.

Comment: Multiply both sides by the denominator on the left. Comparing coefficients of each power of x, you need to prove (1) that coefficients of $\{x,\dots,x^{n-1}\}$ are each 0, and (2) the coefficient of $x^0$ is $n!$. (2) is easy enough to show. Maybe one can show (1) by induction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x(x+1)\cdots(x+n).$ I rewrite your equation  as:

$$\binom n0\frac{f(x)}x-\binom n1\frac{f(x)}{x+1}+\cdots+(-1)^n\binom nn\frac{f(x)}{x+n}=n!$$

with the understanding that the left side is a sum of polynomials.  In other words, each denominator is not really there because it has cancelled a factor of $f(x).$
Thus, the left side is a polynomial of degree at most $n.$  We show that the displayed equation is true for $x=0, -1, -2, \dots, -n$ so that, by interpolation, the equation is true in general.

Each of these substitutions leaves a single term on the left side which we must show is equal to $n!\,.$ When we substitute $-k$ for $x,$ we get

$$(-1)^k\binom nk (-k)\cdots(-1)\cdot 1\cdots(n-k)$$

$$=(-1)^k {n\cdots(n-k-1)\over k!}(-k)\cdots(-1)\cdot 1\cdots(n-k)=n!$$
That's it!  Great question!

Comment: TYPO  $(n-k-1)$ should be $(n-k+1)$