# If $n\in\mathbb N;$ show that $\frac{^nC_0}{x}-\frac{^nC_1}{x+1}+\frac{^nC_2}{x+2}-...+(-1)^n\frac{^nC_n}{x+n}=\frac{n!}{x(x+1)(x+2)...(x+n)}$

Tags: contest-math, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> If $n\in\mathbb N;$ show that $\frac{^nC_0}{x}-\frac{^nC_1}{x+1}+\frac{^nC_2}{x+2}-...+(-1)^n\frac{^nC_n}{x+n}=\frac{n!}{x(x+1)(x+2)...(x+n)}$

RHS$=\frac{n(n-1)!}{x(x+1)(x+2)...(x+n)}$

$=\frac{(x+n-x)(n-1)!}{x(x+1)(x+2)...(x+n)}$

$=\frac{(n-1)!}{x(x+1)...(x+n-1)}-\frac{(n-1)!}{(x+1)(x+2)...(x+n)}$

If I continue like this, I get the sense of LHS being formed.

What's the proper way to prove it?

Can we prove it starting with LHS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving $\frac{n!}{x(x+1)\cdots(x+n)}=\frac{\binom n0}x-\frac{\binom n1}{x+1}+\cdots+(-1)^n\frac{\binom nn}{x+n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4090588/proving-fracnxx1-cdotsxn-frac-binom-n0x-frac-binom-n1x1-c)

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks for the link but it still involves RHS to prove the equality. I wonder if there is a way to prove it by strictly working on LHS and finally getting RHS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiply $x(x+1)\cdots (x+n)$ to the both sides. Then you will find both sides being polynomials of degree $\leq n$.  For polynomials of degree $\leq n$ to be identical, you need to check their values coincides for $n+1$ distinct values. We therefore substitute $x=-k, k= 0, 1, \dots, n$ to the both sides to see if they coincide.

When $x=-k$, we have

$$
LHS = (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}(-k)(-k+1)\cdots (-2)\cdot (-1)\cdot 1 \cdot 2 \cdots (n-k) = n! = RHS.
$$

Since this is true for any $k=0, 1, 2, \dots, n$, we conclude that both sides are identical. Dividing both sides, by $x(x+1)\cdots(x+n)$, we obtain the desired formula.